# Check if collection has changed while accessing it through property

Tags: c#, collections

We've got configuration class that holds all the configuration data as properties. We need to check if configuration has changed so we can make copy of old version during save.

So far it looks like that:

```
class Config
{
    private int propA;
    public int PropA
    {
        get { return propA; }
        set { ConfigChanged = propA != value; propA = value; }
    }

    private List<int> propB;
    public List<int> PropB
    {
        get { return propB; }
        set { ConfigChanged = ????; propB = value; }
    }

    // Ofcourse there is many more...
}
```

Now if someone uses this `config.PropB = new List<int>()` thats fine, we can intercept it in setter. However if someone uses it this way `config.PropB.Add(123)` then we've got the problem, because config has been modified and we dont know it.

We can somehow intercept it if we switch to `ObservableCollection<int>` but that property is already used in few places (including the constructor calls) so for now we would like to avoid changing the type.

I've seen few similar problems with few good answers (like implementing ListEx class or something). We can also add our methods to add/remove new values but its equal to changing type in that case. So I would like to ask:

Is there any way that we can know, if our `PropB` has changed its state without changing the collection type.

Comment: How about implementing the `INotifyProperty`

Comment: Do you really need to expose the whole list? Can't you use  methods like `Add(int value)` which modify the list, then you can set `ConfigChanged` there.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava And how would I know if content of the list has changed (new elements added or old removed) through INotifyProperty?

(at)TimSchmelter I'm not sure if we have to expose whole list, since someone else created the config much ealier. I'll point that out on next team meeting.

Comment: A different approach: How do you save it? Do you serialize to disk? Why not check if it differs while/before saving? That is, if the only reason you want to know is to find out if you need to create a backup copy.

Comment: No there is no way to do that without changing the type.

The only solutions are:
 - Register to `INotifyCollectionChanged` that `List<T>` doesn't support.
 - Derive from `List<T>` and override `Add`, `Remove` and `this[]` but this methods/indexer aren't virtual.

Comment: @Micke Yes, we do serialize it to XML file. Unfortunately we've got hashes  that can actually change even if the value that has been hashed was not changed. So comparing before save may be meaningless since the hashes have changed but values have not :).

Comment: Is it possible to change the type to `IList<T>`? In that case you're able to write a wrapper arround `List<T>` that implements `IList<T>`, forwards all calls to an inner list an raises a changed event.

Comment: @Verarind Not more than changing to `ObservableCollection` I think because both don't provide `AddRange(List<T>)` or `AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)` and we can easily add such method to both types.

Comment: @user2475983 Yes you can add easily that method by creating an extension method `public static void AddRange<T>(this IList<T> target, IEnumerable<T> source) { foreach (var item in source) target.Add(item); }` in a public static class. After that you can call `AddRange` on `IList<T>`. Maybe you've to import your namespace.

Comment: We decided to go for ObservableCollection, CollectionChanged event and extension methods - lowest change cost. Thanks for your contribution. (Made a comment since, imho it does not count as valid reply for the question).